# Facebook graph API not respecting aliases

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a list of URLs of Facebook Pages that I'd like to collect basic metadata from (likes etc).

Most of the time, given a URL:

https://www.facebook.com/cocacola

I can simply fetch the corresponding graph URL:

https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola

Unfortunately, this breaks down for pages whose name has changed:

http://www.facebook.com/bebestores (redirects to https://www.facebook.com/bebe)

The resulting graph URL:

http://graph.facebook.com/bebestores

returns:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: bebestores",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 803
   }
}
```

Can I have the Facebook Graph API follow this redirect, or do I need to hit the public website to check whether my URL redirects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best thing to do is use the page `id`, this never changes.

For `bebe` the id is `46215732881` so you can always get the information by using `http://graph.facebook.com/46215732881` and not worry about the name changing.

Another option is to provide the full URL:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.facebook.com/bebestores
```

I would use this url to get the `id` and use the `id` after that.

Comment: OK, that sounds like it would really help. However, my inputs are arbitrary Facebook URLs -- can I get bebe's page ID when all I know is the page used to be called `bebestores`?

Comment: Found you a better solution, full url

Comment: Hey, I had followed this solution earlier. But I am using login with facebook button to have login on web. It returns ID, access_token etc. But now the ID it is returning is different. And when I do `http://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}` it returns the same error. Any solution ?

Comment: **This doesn't work with groups**. They just return the full URL as `id`. :/